# Discover the same peripheral multiple times in blessed-android

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

In Swift, I start scanning peripherals with:

`central.scanPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : self.allowDuplicateScan])`

And it is allowing multiple discoveries of the same peripheral. So, the delegate `didDiscover` function is called every time the peripheral is seen.

Now, I want to do exactly the same in Android (using blessed-android library). I'm calling `central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(services)` to discover new services. However, the `onDiscoveredPeripheral` callback it's only called once per peripheral. So the question is if it is possible to have the same behavior than Swift?

Comment: In case you do not get an answer here you might want to ask this dierctly to the maintainer here: https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android/issues

Comment: I use the same library for android. What you want is the default behaviour of it. I use it to update RSSI indicators while listing available devices. So you don't need to do anything it must call the `onDiscoveredPeripheral` everytime it receives advertising data from peripherals. Unless you have some bluetooth scanning settings change.

Comment: Please consider specifying the Android version. Because new SDKs might come with new  API and permission modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing multiple discoveries for the same peripheral is the default behaviour of [blessed-android](https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android/tree/master) library so as the Android BLE as long as you don't change the scanning settings of BLE. This is so at least up to Android 13 as far as I know. However things might have been changed for Android 14.

If `onDiscoveredPeripheral` is not getting called multiple times then you can manually change the Android BLE scanner settings to make it to do so by applying the following [`ScanSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#summary) to the `startScan` method:

```java
BluetoothCentralManager centralManager;

// Create a scan settings object and set callback type to CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES
ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                                   .setCallbackType(CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                                   .build();
// Finally pass your scan settings to the startScan method
centralManager.startScan(yourFilterList, scanSettings, yourScanCallback);
```

##### Remarks

- If you want that the BLE scanner call your scan callback for every advertisement then use [`CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) flag for the [`setCallbackType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder#setCallbackType(int)) method.
- If you want that the BLE scanner call your scan callback only once for every reported peripheral then pass the [`CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH) flag to the `setCallbackType` method.

###### NOTE THAT!

The callback types are available for the different API levels of Android SDK. So make sure your app is covering the required API checks.